# jQuery Draggable Element ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've been looking through a lot of tutorials on jQuery draggable and trying to apply it to ASP.NET MVC, but I am really confused.

Does anyone know of some simpler samples.

```
@model locat.Models.LoginModel

@{

    ViewBag.Title = "Log in";
}


    @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "msform" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary()

        <!-- fieldsets -->
    <div id="drag">
        <fieldset>
            <h2 class="fs-title">Login</h2>
            <h3 class="fs-subtitle"></h3>

            <input name="UserName" type="text" placeholder="Username">
            <input name="Password" type="Password" placeholder="Password">
            <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="New User" />

            <input type="submit" name="next" class="nexts action-login" value="Log in" />
        </fieldset>

    </div>
    }

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#drag").draggable();
    });
</script>

    @section Scripts {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    }
```

Comment: include js files also.

Comment: is there is any errors in console??

Comment: got nothing : smiply it displays the element alone.can't able to drag

Comment: have u included jquery and jquery-ui files???

Comment: add these files in ur head tag.<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

Comment: yes i already included those files

Comment: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>  Still got Nothing .i little confused
<link rel="stylesheet" href="code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one of these problems :-

1. Your jQuery or jQuery UI Javascript path files are wrong.
2. Your jQuery UI does not include draggable.
3. Your div is unstyled or empty, therefore there is nothing to drag.
4. Something is colliding with your jQuery or jQuery UI so it doesn't
   work.

In your question ur div with id="drag" in not styled so give style to it so that draggable will work on it.

Comment: Thank you very much Kartikeya Khosla : Now its working greatly. The problem is its not styled.

Answer (score 0):

ut your dragable elements inside Ul as below and don't forget to include Jquery UI files reference:

```
<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
 <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

AND Jquery:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#sortable" ).draggable({       
  });     
});
```

**Working Demo Is Here**  http://jsfiddle.net/booyaa/YvJhE/

Comment: Plsase include JQuery Ui Reference
http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js

Comment: Thank u very much Pawan .Now its Working greatly: